# hamming code parity distribution issue

Tags: bit, parity, hamming-code

Can someone please clarify where im going wrong. I'm at this 2 hours... I know that the first parity in the code includes itself and skips every first number after it in a yes and no sequence. the second skips every second set of numbers after itself and the following number. The 4th should skip 4 after including itself and the first 3 numbers.

```
These are my message bits in its original form: 1101011011000110 
   and I want to add the hamming parity bits onto them.
   ? = Parity
so this means ??1?101?01101100011?0 
Parity 1 = ?110110010 
Parity 2 = ?101111011 
Parity 3 = ?1010110?0 (this is where my issue is so I cant move on)
Parity 4 = cant get to this part...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the 5th parity bit in the wrong location.

You have:

> ??1?101?01101100011?0

But it should be:

> ??1?101?0110110?00110

So, recalculating the parity bits (bold means "keep", otherwise skip), we follow the pattern "keep 1, skip 1, keep 1...":

**?** ? **1** ? **1** 0 **1** ? **0** 1 **1** 0 **1** 1 **0** ? **0** 0 **1** 1 **0**

```
P1: ?1110110010 (even number of 1s, so 0 parity)
```

(discard first 1 bit) Follow the pattern "keep 2, skip 2, keep 2...":

**?1** ?1 **01** ?0 **11** 01 **10** ?0 **01** 10

```
P2: ?101111001 (even number of 1s, so 0 parity)
```

(discard next 2 bits) Follow the pattern "keep 4, skip 4, keep 4...":

**?101** ?011 **0110** ?0011 **0**

```
P4: ?10101100 (even number of 1s, so 0 parity)
```

(discard next 4 bits) Follow the pattern "keep 8, skip 8, keep 8..." (but we can only do keep 8, skip 6, so that's good enough here):

**?0110110** ?00110

```
P5: ?0110110 (even number of 1s, so 0 parity)
```

So the final, hamming (21,16) encoded value is:

```
001010100110110000110
```

(21 bits, 16 of which are data bits)